# Vertically aligning text within input in Firefox - Windows only

Tags: css

This is probably a simple fix but I cannot find out how to vertically align my text in firefox on a PC.

I am using this text which I have always used to center:

```
input.input_search_bg {
  background: url("../images/input_search.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  color: #145D94;
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
    height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin: 0 7px 0 0;
  padding: 0 8px 0 7px;
  width: 266px;
}
```

I have the line-height centering it, and on a Mac it looks great. But when I test on for FF 3.0 on a PC it isnt aligned. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

HTML for that section:

```
            <div class="top_search">
                <form>
                    <div class="search_box">
                        <input type="text" value="Search" class="tog input_search_bg" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="search_submit_btn" />
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please include the HTML code.

Comment: out of interest, why are you testing in Firefox 3.0? That's a very old version of Firefox. The latest version is v5, but even if you want to stick with v3, you should upgrade to 3.6 for security reasons.

Comment: I was checking in Browserlab just making my rounds for various browsers. And believe me I agree 100% about upgrading.

Comment: I usually use vertical padding & leave my line-height at 1, since line-height seems to be treated differently in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly firefox (don't know all versions) doesn't allow to specify your own line-height on `input` elements: http://www.cssnewbie.com/input-button-line-height-bug/

You have to play with `font-size` and/or `padding`.

Answer (score 0):

Give padding-bottom,

```
input.input_search_bg {
  background: url("../images/input_search.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  color: #145D94;
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
    height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin: 0 7px 0 0;
  padding: 0 8px 4px 7px;
  width: 266px;
}
```